# How to design a Real Time B2B Ecommerce Database Structure?

Tags: database-design, architecture, relational-database, system-design

I want to design a database structure for b2b ecommerce application . here is the situation 
supplier can sell multiple products at different profit slabs to different wholesellers (Relationship between supplier and wholeseller is many to many).

similarly wholeseller can sell to retailer (Many to many relationship between wholeseller and retailer) .

also retailer can sell to customer (many to many relation exists between retailer and customer)

example

s1 supplier can sell p1 product to w1 wholeseller at profit pr1%

s1 supplier can sell p2 product to w1 wholeseller at profit pr2%

s1 supplier can sell p1 product to w2 wholeseller at profit pr3%

s1 supplier can sell p2 product to w2 wholeseller at profit pr4%

how to design this type of model and what fields should be there in it ?

You can help me with supplier and wholeseller table only ?

Also i want to store the transaction done by let say customer , i want to distribute profits to each one of supplier,wholeseller,retailer,customer . How can i store any transaction for this use case ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd go this way:

```
CREATE TABLE margins (
    id serial PRIMARY KEY,
    supplier_id int NOT NULL,
    product_id int NOT NULL,
    wholesaler_id int, -- NULL-able. NULL value indicates that it's a default value for all wholesalers
    margin numeric NOT NULL default 0.01
    -- TODO: foreign keys here
)
```

So, you set a particular margin (1%, 2%, 3%, 4%...) for a particular product from a particular supplier. Then you either assign the margin to a particular wholesaler or you leave the `wholesaler_id` empty and this would serve as a default value to all wholesalers that do not have a specific margin for a given product.

Comment: thanks for the reply . can you help me with the use case  => storing transaction to distribute profits  ( given above in last )